# Should use Workflow rule/Trigger/Apex Code

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, scheduled-apex

I'm new to SF and working through my way and I need some recommendation or best practice from people who have been working heavily in the SF.

My question is: I have the following requirement:

if the `calendar interval >= 90` days then `create an entry` in the `order object`

the above logic should be execute on the custom object but I'm not sure where I should implement should I do it on `Triggers or Workflow or ApexCode`?

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have the calendar interval as static value (not dynamic i.e. changing with each day) and its about creating records in custom objects, you can achieve it by either of following:-

1. Writing apex trigger
2. [Use process builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm)

Comment: what do you mean by `apex trigger` does it mean creating trigger and calling from apex code?

Comment: A trigger in Salesforce is written using apex itself. So essentially, a trigger is an Apex Trigger. However, as a best practice, you can have trigger invoke an apex class, wherein the business logic resides within apex class and invocation is done from trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Using workflow you cannot create records so far. Only actions that are available can be found in below link,

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_actions.htm&language=en_US

But in latest release Salesforce has released a pilot feature called flow trigger, using which you might be able to create record from workflow. Please check,

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_flow_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

But since this feature is in pilot I will go for apex trigger in this scenario.

Comment: what do you mean by `apex trigger` does it mean creating trigger and calling from apex code?

Comment: apex:trigger doesn't need to be called separately. It will be executed automatically when you create/edit/delete record based on conditions.

Comment: Apex Triggers are triggers and are invoked automatically based on the trigger context. Since it is apex programming based, it is referred as apex trigger. <br> refer these links for apex trigger <br> https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm  <br>  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm